# conda/mamba can't solve tensorflow_probability and tensorflow dependencies

Tags: tensorflow, conda, miniconda, tensorflow-probability, mamba

## Problem

I am trying to create a conda environment and it seems that conda/mamba can't resolve `tensorflow_probability` dependencies with respect to `tensorflow`.

### More context

I am trying to create a conda environment with the following requirements using mamba:

```
numpy
pandas
mitosheet
jupyter
tensorflow-gpu
tensorflow-probability
scikit-learn
matplotlib 
scikit-survival
openpyx
wandb
```

All works fine during the installation and I end up with the following installed versions:

```
$ conda list tensorflow
# packages in environment at /home/luca/miniconda3/envs/liver:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensorflow                2.4.1           gpu_py39h8236f22_0  
tensorflow-base           2.4.1           gpu_py39h29c2da4_0  
tensorflow-estimator      2.6.0            py39he80948d_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-gpu            2.4.1                h30adc30_0  
tensorflow-probability    0.15.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
```

However, when I try to use it I get a version incompatibility error. Precisely, when I run:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
```

I get this error:

```
2022-12-21 11:32:29.516053: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 import tensorflow_probability as tfp

File ~/miniconda3/envs/liver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/__init__.py:20, in <module>
     15 """Tools for probabilistic reasoning in TensorFlow."""
     17 # Contributors to the `python/` dir should not alter this file; instead update
     18 # `python/__init__.py` as necessary.
---> 20 from tensorflow_probability import substrates
     21 # from tensorflow_probability.google import staging  # DisableOnExport
     22 # from tensorflow_probability.google import tfp_google  # DisableOnExport
     23 from tensorflow_probability.python import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import

File ~/miniconda3/envs/liver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/substrates/__init__.py:17, in <module>
      1 # Copyright 2019 The TensorFlow Probability Authors.
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     13 # limitations under the License.
     14 # ============================================================================
     15 """TensorFlow Probability alternative substrates."""
---> 17 from tensorflow_probability.python.internal import all_util
     18 from tensorflow_probability.python.internal import lazy_loader  # pylint: disable=g-direct-tensorflow-import
     21 jax = lazy_loader.LazyLoader(
     22     'jax', globals(),
     23     'tensorflow_probability.substrates.jax')

File ~/miniconda3/envs/liver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/__init__.py:138, in <module>
    135 if _tf_loaded():
    136   # Non-lazy load of packages that register with tensorflow or keras.
    137   for pkg_name in _maybe_nonlazy_load:
--> 138     dir(globals()[pkg_name])  # Forces loading the package from its lazy loader.
    141 all_util.remove_undocumented(__name__, _lazy_load + _maybe_nonlazy_load)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/liver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/internal/lazy_loader.py:57, in LazyLoader.__dir__(self)
     56 def __dir__(self):
---> 57   module = self._load()
     58   return dir(module)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/liver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/internal/lazy_loader.py:37, in LazyLoader._load(self)
     35 """Load the module and insert it into the parent's globals."""
     36 if callable(self._on_first_access):
---> 37   self._on_first_access()
     38   self._on_first_access = None
     39 # Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace

File ~/miniconda3/envs/liver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/__init__.py:59, in _validate_tf_environment(package)
     55 #   required_tensorflow_version = '1.15'  # Needed internally -- DisableOnExport
     57   if (distutils.version.LooseVersion(tf.__version__) <
     58       distutils.version.LooseVersion(required_tensorflow_version)):
---> 59     raise ImportError(
     60         'This version of TensorFlow Probability requires TensorFlow '
     61         'version >= {required}; Detected an installation of version {present}. '
     62         'Please upgrade TensorFlow to proceed.'.format(
     63             required=required_tensorflow_version,
     64             present=tf.__version__))
     66   if (package == 'mcmc' and
     67       tf.config.experimental.tensor_float_32_execution_enabled()):
     68     # Must import here, because symbols get pruned to __all__.
     69     import warnings

ImportError: This version of TensorFlow Probability requires TensorFlow version >= 2.7; Detected an installation of version 2.4.1. Please upgrade TensorFlow to proceed.
```

### Solving attempts

Looking online I found some related discussions in [[1]](https://github.com/conda-forge/tensorflow-probability-feedstock/issues/3) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65740676/problem-with-importing-tensorflow-probability), where they seem to point at some problem in resolving dependencies of tensorflow/tensorflow_probability packages on conda repositories (unfortunately I am not sufficiently competent to fully understand the whole thread).

The same conclusion seems suggested also in [conda-forge documentation](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html) with some additional reference to `cudatoolkit`.

From here, I tried to:

1. upgrade tensorflow:

```
$ CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA="11.2" mamba install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu==2.7=cuda112*

Looking for: ['tensorflow-gpu==2.7[build=cuda112*]']

pkgs/r/linux-64                                               No change
pkgs/main/noarch                                              No change
pkgs/main/linux-64                                            No change
pkgs/r/noarch                                                 No change
conda-forge/noarch                                 @   3.4MB/s  3.5s
conda-forge/linux-64                               @   3.3MB/s  9.8s

Pinned packages:
  - python 3.9.*


Could not solve for environment specs
Encountered problems while solving:
  - package libxml2-2.10.3-h7463322_0 requires icu >=70.1,<71.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed

The environment can't be solved, aborting the operation
```

I also tried with conda directly but this is what I get:

```
$ CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA="11.2" conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu==2.7=cuda112*
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: - / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                          

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__cuda==11.2=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__cuda==11.2=0
  - tensorflow-gpu==2.7[build=cuda112*] -> tensorflow==2.7.0=cuda112py37h01c6645_0 -> __cuda

Your installed version is: 11.2
```

### Additional info

I installed the packages one by one manually using `Miniconda` with `conda==4.12.0` and running `mamba install` (`mamba=1.1.0`). I followed the order in the above requirements.

If I check the evolution of versions at each step with `conda list --revisions`, I can see that `tensorflow` VS `tensorflow_probability` probability was first resolved correctly as it installed `tensorflow==2.10.0` and `tensorflow_probability=0.19.0` (see *rev 1* and *rev 2* in the output below).
However, I guess the environment was broken when installing `matplotlib` (see *rev 4*).

Here's the full output, where *rev 0* comes from cloning another environment:

```
2022-12-20 17:16:58  (rev 0)
    +_libgcc_mutex-0.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +_openmp_mutex-4.5 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +alsa-lib-1.2.8 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +anyio-3.5.0 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +argon2-cffi-21.3.0 (anaconda/noarch)
    +argon2-cffi-bindings-21.2.0 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +asttokens-2.0.5 (anaconda/noarch)
    +attr-2.5.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +attrs-21.4.0 (anaconda/noarch)
    +autopep8-2.0.1 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +babel-2.9.1 (anaconda/noarch)
    +backcall-0.2.0 (anaconda/noarch)
    +beautifulsoup4-4.11.1 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +blas-1.0 (defaults/linux-64)
    +bleach-4.1.0 (anaconda/noarch)
    +bottleneck-1.3.5 (defaults/linux-64)
    +brotlipy-0.7.0 (defaults/linux-64)
    +bzip2-1.0.8 (defaults/linux-64)
    +c-ares-1.18.1 (defaults/linux-64)
    +ca-certificates-2022.12.7 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +certifi-2022.12.7 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +cffi-1.15.1 (defaults/linux-64)
    +charset-normalizer-2.0.4 (defaults/noarch)
    +conda-package-handling-1.9.0 (defaults/linux-64)
    +cryptography-38.0.1 (defaults/linux-64)
    +dbus-1.13.18 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +debugpy-1.5.1 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +decorator-5.1.1 (anaconda/noarch)
    +defusedxml-0.7.1 (anaconda/noarch)
    +entrypoints-0.4 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +executing-0.8.3 (anaconda/noarch)
    +expat-2.5.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +fftw-3.3.10 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +fmt-9.1.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono-2.37 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +font-ttf-inconsolata-3.000 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +font-ttf-source-code-pro-2.038 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +font-ttf-ubuntu-0.83 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +fontconfig-2.14.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +fonts-conda-ecosystem-1 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +fonts-conda-forge-1 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +freetype-2.12.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +gettext-0.21.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +giflib-5.2.1 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +glib-2.74.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +glib-tools-2.74.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +gst-plugins-base-1.21.2 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +gstreamer-1.21.2 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +gstreamer-orc-0.4.33 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +icu-70.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +idna-3.4 (defaults/linux-64)
    +intel-openmp-2021.4.0 (defaults/linux-64)
    +ipykernel-6.9.1 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +ipython-8.4.0 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +ipython_genutils-0.2.0 (anaconda/noarch)
    +ipywidgets-7.6.5 (anaconda/noarch)
    +jack-1.9.21 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +jedi-0.18.1 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +jinja2-3.0.3 (anaconda/noarch)
    +jpeg-9e (anaconda/linux-64)
    +json5-0.9.6 (anaconda/noarch)
    +jsonschema-4.4.0 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +jupyter-1.0.0 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +jupyter_client-7.2.2 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +jupyter_console-6.4.3 (anaconda/noarch)
    +jupyter_contrib_core-0.4.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +jupyter_contrib_nbextensions-0.7.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +jupyter_core-4.10.0 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +jupyter_highlight_selected_word-0.2.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +jupyter_latex_envs-1.4.6 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +jupyter_nbextensions_configurator-0.6.1 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +jupyter_server-1.18.1 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +jupyterlab-3.4.4 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2 (anaconda/noarch)
    +jupyterlab_server-2.12.0 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +jupyterlab_widgets-1.0.0 (anaconda/noarch)
    +keyutils-1.6.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +krb5-1.20.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +lame-3.100 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +ld_impl_linux-64-2.38 (defaults/linux-64)
    +lerc-4.0.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libarchive-3.5.2 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libcap-2.66 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libclang-15.0.6 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libclang13-15.0.6 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libcups-2.3.3 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libcurl-7.86.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libdb-6.2.32 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libdeflate-1.14 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libedit-3.1.20221030 (defaults/linux-64)
    +libev-4.33 (defaults/linux-64)
    +libevent-2.1.10 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libffi-3.4.2 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libflac-1.4.2 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libgcc-ng-12.2.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libgcrypt-1.10.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libgfortran-ng-12.2.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libgfortran5-12.2.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libglib-2.74.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libgomp-12.2.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libgpg-error-1.45 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libiconv-1.17 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libllvm10-10.0.1 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +libllvm15-15.0.6 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libmamba-1.1.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libmambapy-1.1.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libnghttp2-1.47.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libnsl-2.0.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libogg-1.3.4 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libopus-1.3.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libpng-1.6.39 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libpq-15.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libsndfile-1.1.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libsodium-1.0.18 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +libsolv-0.7.22 (defaults/linux-64)
    +libsqlite-3.40.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libssh2-1.10.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libstdcxx-ng-12.2.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libsystemd0-252 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libtiff-4.5.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libtool-2.4.6 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libudev1-252 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libuuid-2.32.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libvorbis-1.3.7 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libwebp-1.2.4 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libwebp-base-1.2.4 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libxcb-1.13 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libxkbcommon-1.0.3 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libxml2-2.10.3 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libxslt-1.1.37 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libzlib-1.2.13 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +lxml-4.9.2 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +lz4-c-1.9.4 (defaults/linux-64)
    +lzo-2.10 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +markupsafe-2.1.1 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +matplotlib-inline-0.1.2 (anaconda/noarch)
    +mistune-0.8.4 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +mkl-2021.4.0 (defaults/linux-64)
    +mkl-service-2.4.0 (defaults/linux-64)
    +mkl_fft-1.3.1 (defaults/linux-64)
    +mkl_random-1.2.2 (defaults/linux-64)
    +mpg123-1.31.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +mysql-common-8.0.31 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +mysql-libs-8.0.31 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +nb_conda_kernels-2.3.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +nbclassic-0.3.5 (anaconda/noarch)
    +nbclient-0.5.13 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +nbconvert-6.4.4 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +nbformat-5.3.0 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +ncurses-6.3 (defaults/linux-64)
    +nest-asyncio-1.5.5 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +notebook-6.4.12 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +nspr-4.35 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +nss-3.82 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +numexpr-2.8.4 (defaults/linux-64)
    +numpy-1.23.4 (defaults/linux-64)
    +numpy-base-1.23.4 (defaults/linux-64)
    +openssl-3.0.7 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +packaging-21.3 (anaconda/noarch)
    +pandas-1.5.2 (defaults/linux-64)
    +pandocfilters-1.5.0 (anaconda/noarch)
    +parso-0.8.3 (anaconda/noarch)
    +pcre-8.45 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +pcre2-10.37 (defaults/linux-64)
    +pexpect-4.8.0 (anaconda/noarch)
    +pickleshare-0.7.5 (anaconda/noarch)
    +pip-22.3.1 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +ply-3.11 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +prometheus_client-0.14.1 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +prompt-toolkit-3.0.20 (anaconda/noarch)
    +prompt_toolkit-3.0.20 (anaconda/noarch)
    +pthread-stubs-0.4 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +ptyprocess-0.7.0 (anaconda/noarch)
    +pulseaudio-16.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +pure_eval-0.2.2 (anaconda/noarch)
    +pybind11-abi-4 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +pycodestyle-2.10.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +pycosat-0.6.4 (defaults/linux-64)
    +pycparser-2.21 (defaults/noarch)
    +pygments-2.11.2 (anaconda/noarch)
    +pyopenssl-22.0.0 (defaults/noarch)
    +pyparsing-3.0.4 (anaconda/noarch)
    +pyqt-5.15.7 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +pyqt5-sip-12.11.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +pyrsistent-0.18.0 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +pysocks-1.7.1 (defaults/linux-64)
    +python-3.9.15 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +python-dateutil-2.8.2 (anaconda/noarch)
    +python-fastjsonschema-2.15.1 (anaconda/noarch)
    +python_abi-3.9 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +pytz-2022.1 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +pyyaml-6.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +pyzmq-23.2.0 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +qt-main-5.15.6 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +qt-webengine-5.15.4 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +qtconsole-5.3.1 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +qtpy-2.0.1 (anaconda/noarch)
    +qtwebkit-5.212 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +readline-8.2 (defaults/linux-64)
    +reproc-14.2.4 (defaults/linux-64)
    +reproc-cpp-14.2.4 (defaults/linux-64)
    +requests-2.28.1 (defaults/linux-64)
    +ruamel_yaml-0.15.100 (defaults/linux-64)
    +send2trash-1.8.0 (anaconda/noarch)
    +setuptools-65.5.0 (defaults/linux-64)
    +sip-6.7.5 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +six-1.16.0 (anaconda/noarch)
    +sniffio-1.2.0 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +soupsieve-2.3.1 (anaconda/noarch)
    +sqlite-3.40.0 (defaults/linux-64)
    +stack_data-0.2.0 (anaconda/noarch)
    +terminado-0.13.1 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +testpath-0.6.0 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +tk-8.6.12 (defaults/linux-64)
    +toml-0.10.2 (anaconda/noarch)
    +tomli-2.0.1 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +tornado-6.1 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +tqdm-4.64.1 (defaults/linux-64)
    +traitlets-5.1.1 (anaconda/noarch)
    +typing-extensions-4.3.0 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +typing_extensions-4.3.0 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +tzdata-2022g (defaults/noarch)
    +urllib3-1.26.13 (defaults/linux-64)
    +wcwidth-0.2.5 (anaconda/noarch)
    +webencodings-0.5.1 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +websocket-client-0.58.0 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +wheel-0.38.4 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +widgetsnbextension-3.5.2 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +xcb-util-0.4.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +xcb-util-image-0.4.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +xcb-util-keysyms-0.4.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +xcb-util-renderutil-0.3.9 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +xcb-util-wm-0.4.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +xorg-libxau-1.0.9 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +xorg-libxdmcp-1.1.3 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +xz-5.2.8 (defaults/linux-64)
    +yaml-0.2.5 (defaults/linux-64)
    +yaml-cpp-0.7.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +yapf-0.32.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +zeromq-4.3.4 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +zlib-1.2.13 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +zstd-1.5.2 (defaults/linux-64)

2022-12-20 17:18:38  (rev 1)
     krb5  {1.20.1 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 1.20.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libarchive  {3.5.2 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 3.5.2 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libcurl  {7.86.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 7.86.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libevent  {2.1.10 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 2.1.10 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libmamba  {1.1.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 1.1.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libmambapy  {1.1.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 1.1.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libnghttp2  {1.47.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 1.47.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libpq  {15.1 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 15.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libssh2  {1.10.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 1.10.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     mysql-common  {8.0.31 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 8.0.31 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     mysql-libs  {8.0.31 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 8.0.31 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     openssl  {3.0.7 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 1.1.1s (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     pulseaudio  {16.1 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 16.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     python  {3.9.15 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 3.9.15 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     qt-main  {5.15.6 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 5.15.6 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
    +absl-py-1.3.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +aiohttp-3.8.3 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +aiosignal-1.3.1 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +astunparse-1.6.3 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +async-timeout-4.0.2 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +blinker-1.5 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +cached-property-1.5.2 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +cached_property-1.5.2 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +cachetools-5.2.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +click-8.1.3 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +cudatoolkit-11.8.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +cudnn-8.4.1.50 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +flatbuffers-2.0.8 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +frozenlist-1.3.3 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +gast-0.4.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +google-auth-2.15.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.6 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +google-pasta-0.2.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +grpc-cpp-1.47.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +grpcio-1.47.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +h5py-3.7.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +hdf5-1.12.2 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +importlib-metadata-5.2.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +keras-2.10.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +keras-preprocessing-1.1.2 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +libabseil-20220623.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libblas-3.9.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libcblas-3.9.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +liblapack-3.9.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libprotobuf-3.21.11 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +markdown-3.4.1 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +multidict-6.0.2 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +nccl-2.14.3.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +oauthlib-3.2.2 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +opt_einsum-3.3.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +protobuf-4.21.11 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +pyasn1-0.4.8 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +pyasn1-modules-0.2.7 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +pyjwt-2.6.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +python-flatbuffers-22.12.6 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +pyu2f-0.1.5 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +re2-2022.06.01 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +requests-oauthlib-1.3.1 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +rsa-4.9 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +scipy-1.9.3 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +snappy-1.1.9 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +tensorboard-2.10.1 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +tensorboard-data-server-0.6.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.8.1 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +tensorflow-2.10.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +tensorflow-base-2.10.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +tensorflow-estimator-2.10.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +tensorflow-gpu-2.10.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +termcolor-2.1.1 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +werkzeug-2.2.2 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +wrapt-1.14.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +yarl-1.8.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +zipp-3.11.0 (conda-forge/noarch)

2022-12-20 17:20:43  (rev 2)
    +cloudpickle-2.2.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +dm-tree-0.1.7 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +etils-0.9.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +importlib_resources-5.10.1 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +jax-0.3.17 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +jaxlib-0.3.15 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +tensorflow-probability-0.19.0 (conda-forge/noarch)

2022-12-20 17:21:31  (rev 3)
    +joblib-1.1.0 (anaconda/noarch)
    +scikit-learn-1.1.1 (anaconda/linux-64)
    +threadpoolctl-2.2.0 (anaconda/noarch)

2022-12-20 17:24:10  (rev 4)
     cudatoolkit  {11.8.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 10.1.243 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     cudnn  {8.4.1.50 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 7.6.5.32 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     grpc-cpp  {1.47.1 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 1.51.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     grpcio  {1.47.1 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 1.51.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     h5py  {3.7.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 2.10.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     hdf5  {1.12.2 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 1.10.6 (defaults/linux-64)}
     jax  {0.3.17 (conda-forge/noarch) -> 0.4.1 (conda-forge/noarch)}
     jaxlib  {0.3.15 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 0.4.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     keras  {2.10.0 (conda-forge/noarch) -> 2.4.3 (conda-forge/noarch)}
     krb5  {1.20.1 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 1.20.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libarchive  {3.5.2 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 3.5.2 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libcurl  {7.86.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 7.86.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libevent  {2.1.10 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 2.1.10 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libmamba  {1.1.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 1.1.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libmambapy  {1.1.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 1.1.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libnghttp2  {1.47.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 1.47.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libpq  {15.1 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 15.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     libssh2  {1.10.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 1.10.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     mysql-common  {8.0.31 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 8.0.31 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     mysql-libs  {8.0.31 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 8.0.31 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     nccl  {2.14.3.1 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 2.11.4.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     openssl  {1.1.1s (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 3.0.7 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     pulseaudio  {16.1 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 16.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     python  {3.9.15 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 3.9.15 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     qt-main  {5.15.6 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 5.15.6 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     tensorboard-data-server  {0.6.1 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 0.6.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     tensorflow  {2.10.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 2.4.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     tensorflow-base  {2.10.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 2.4.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     tensorflow-estimator  {2.10.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 2.6.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
     tensorflow-gpu  {2.10.0 (conda-forge/linux-64) -> 2.4.1 (defaults/linux-64)}
     tensorflow-probability  {0.19.0 (conda-forge/noarch) -> 0.15.0 (conda-forge/noarch)}
    +_tflow_select-2.1.0 (defaults/linux-64)
    +astor-0.8.1 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +brotli-1.0.9 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +brotli-bin-1.0.9 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +contourpy-1.0.6 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +cupti-10.1.168 (defaults/linux-64)
    +cycler-0.11.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +fonttools-4.38.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +kiwisolver-1.4.4 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +lcms2-2.14 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libbrotlicommon-1.0.9 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libbrotlidec-1.0.9 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libbrotlienc-1.0.9 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libgrpc-1.51.1 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +matplotlib-3.6.2 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +matplotlib-base-3.6.2 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +munkres-1.1.4 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +openjpeg-2.5.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +pillow-9.2.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +unicodedata2-15.0.0 (conda-forge/linux-64)

2022-12-20 17:25:29  (rev 5)
     scikit-learn  {1.1.1 (anaconda/linux-64) -> 1.1.3 (conda-forge/linux-64)}
    +ecos-2.0.11 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +libqdldl-0.1.5 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +osqp-0.6.2.post0 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +qdldl-python-0.1.5.post2 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +scikit-survival-0.19.0.post1 (conda-forge/linux-64)

2022-12-20 17:34:12  (rev 6)
    +docker-pycreds-0.4.0 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +gitdb-4.0.10 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +gitpython-3.1.29 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +pathtools-0.1.2 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +promise-2.3 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +psutil-5.9.4 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +sentry-sdk-1.12.1 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +setproctitle-1.3.2 (conda-forge/linux-64)
    +shortuuid-1.0.11 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +smmap-3.0.5 (conda-forge/noarch)
    +wandb-0.13.7 (conda-forge/noarch)
```

**Edit:** the imports apparently work with inverted order:

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import tensorflow as tf

print(f"{tf.__version__=}, {tfp.__version__=}")
```

gives `tf.__version__='2.4.1', tfp.__version__='0.15.0'`

Comment: There are [some metadata problems](https://github.com/conda-forge/tensorflow-probability-feedstock/issues/40) with the Conda Forge TFP package. Explicitly providing versions should overcome this. Instead of updating TF, consider downgrading the TFP, as your environment seems incompatible with newer TF builds.

Comment: Also, the situation is not helped by doing one-by-one installations. It would be far easier to help if the environment was defined by a YAML that specifies the actual needs for the project. Designing a new environment for the project is far easier than trying to mutate an existing environment to accommodate multiple projects.

Comment: Thanks @merv! regarding the new VS cloned environment, I am trying to setup the base conda env with common packages I use for all projects (at the moment jupyter, pandas and numpy). Then the idea is to clone this for each new project and add specific dependencies. The principal goal is to avoid re-installing jupyter notebook with all nbextensions and their configurations. Does it make sense or would you still suggest avoiding this and re-installing from scratch each time?

Comment: I generally recommend only one copy of Jupyter be installed in a dedicated environment, together with `nb_conda_kernels`. As long as other environments have `ipykernel` (or `r-irkernel` for R), then the environments will automatically be registered as kernels. That is, one can keep the Jupyter infrastructure independent of the kernels, which also means a single point of updating.

Comment: That would be great but unfortunately doesn't seem to work. If I run jupyter notebook from the notebook environment I can successfully start new notebooks and select other envs as kernels, however I can't open an older notebook and change the kernel. Is this supposed to work only for new notebooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solved by creating the conda environment and then installing all packages via pip directly, as per [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).

[**IMPORTANTLY**:](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment) I figured that in general it is advised to install as many packages as possible using conda and then use pip for the unresolved dependencies. After that, the environment should better be freezed, and a new environment should be created for installing new packages.